# WSO2 - OAuth Access Token Validation and Multi-Tenant support

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2

I am new to WSO2 and have these questions related to security and Multi-Tenant.

**Security**
I like to use client credentials grant to generate the access token to access the resources managed by API manager.  I see access token gets validated by API Manager and passed to the backend resource (my application code).   I would like to secure the call from API manager to the backend.  How can I do this aside from using SSL?  Can I rely on the same access token to meet my resource security needs?  If so, how can i validate the access token in my application code?   I see some links referring to using WSO2 identity server to validate but i like to keep my WSO2 foot print to a minimum to API manager only.

**Multi-Tenant**
My application code need to support multi-tenant and it requires a tenant ID to identify the tenant for isolating the functions available and data access.   Can this tenant ID be settable during client ID and Secret Key generation during publishing/subscribing phase?  Can the API Manager automatically inject/set this tenant ID in a HTTP header when it forwards the calls from this client ID to the backend?

I could very well use the client ID itself as a tenant ID but this client ID is managed by WSO2 that i don't have control over its generation.  Also there is only one client ID per subscription/application.

Answer (score 0):

**Security:** You can set a security scheme for the API's endpoint, which is your backend service. APIM supports [Basic auth](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Basic+Auth) and [Digest auth](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Digest+Auth) for endpoints.

**Multi-tenancy:** You can publish an API to be available for all tenants. Steps are,

1. Set `Visibility=public` in Design page.
2. Set `Subscriptions=Available to all the tenants` in Manage page.

Then any tenant developer can subscribe to your API with their tenant specific applications. Then you can either use `client key` or `tenant domain` to identify the tenant at backend. See below blog post on how to get those values to be sent to the backend.

http://movingaheadblog.blogspot.com/2016/08/wso2-api-manager-how-to-retrieve.html